# Method not a static member of a class

Tags: c++, class, header

Hello guys i had this error while i was compiling

```
error:'unisgned int vehicle::accelerate' is not a static member of 'class vehicle'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Header file

```
class vehicle
{
    public:
    enum Switch
    {
     SWITCH_ON=0,
     SWITCH_OFF
                };
     vehicle();
    ~vehicle();

    bool powerSwitch(Switch );
    unsigned int accelerate(unsigned int );
    unsigned int decelerate(unsigned int );
    bool isMoving();
    unsigned int getSpeed();
    unsigned int setSpeed(unsigned int);

private:
unsigned int speed;
bool moving;
};
```

vehicle.cpp

```
unsigned int vehicle::accelerate(amount)
{

if(moving==true;){
speed+=amount;
 }

 return speed;

 }
```

Comment: It's definition should be `unsigned int vehicle::accelerate(unsigned int amount)`.

Comment: Your if statement should omit the semicolon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the type in the parameter list:

```
unsigned int vehicle::accelerate(unsigned int amount)
{
  .....
}
```

Comment: +1 what a positively odd error for a bogus param. K&R-panic-mode on the compiler? =P

Comment: @WhozCraig, Well, the original code *did* have this: `vehicle::accelerate(amount)`.

Comment: @chris yeah, i saw that, I just though the error he was reporting was completely odd for what is actually wrong with the function def. Methinks that error (the static member err) is unrelated, and since we've no line number to match up, we'll prolly never know where it was coming from

Comment: @Nobody Ah. makes sense then. two errors (busted def, invalid invoke). thx. I was really head-scratching there for a min.

Answer (score 3):

As you have declared:

```
unsigned int accelerate(unsigned int );
```

So you must implement:

```
unsigned int vehicle::accelerate(unsigned int amount)
{
  //...
```

The type needs to be given again at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The error might be somewhere else, where you're trying to access the `accelerate` member not using the operator `->` or `.`, but `::`, apart from forgetting the type of the parameter

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    vehicle t;


    t.setSpeed(5);
    cout<<t.isMoving<<" "<<t.getSpeed;

    t.accelerate(15);
    cout<<t.isMoving<<" "<<t.getSpeed;

    t.decelerate(7);
    cout<<t.isMoving<<" "<<t.getSpeed;

    t.accelerate(3);
    cout<<t.isMoving<<" "<<t.getSpeed;


    t.powerSwitch(0);


    cout<<endl;

    }

Comment: this is how i call the method

Comment: @user1750901, You're missing brackets on `isMoving()`.

Comment: @user1750901 Edit this code into your question and please mark the line the error message is related to.